# What information does iPhone 4S Log-Aggregated 2012-12-12 contain?

Tags: iphone, logs

On the iPhone under the Settings > General > About > Diagnostics & Usage Data > log aggregated, what does this mean?

```
<key>appActivationCount.com.apple.MobileSMS</key> <integer>9</integer>
```

Does it mean the number of text sent or received or both?

Comment: Is there anything else I can add to my answer to help you?

Answer (score 1):

It means that that program (the SMS application) was started 9 times on that day.

Whether that corresponds to someone checking the app in response to a message or simply entering the app isn't logged in that file. I don't know offhand if you can reconstruct that level of detail from any of the standard logs on iOS so you may need a forensic analysis of either the database the SMS app uses or the network / server side of things to track down delivery times or even something as detailed as a daily count of SMS messages.